# TSQL retrieve all records in current month/year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a datetime field called DateFinished.  I need to be able to retrieve all records in which DateFinished is within the current month/year.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you've only got a small number of rows, this will do to get all rows where `DateFinished` is in this month of this year.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE Year(DateFinished) = Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                 AND Month(DateFinished) = Month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This could get quite slow over a large number of rows though - in which case using `DateAdd`, `DatePart` and `BETWEEN` is probably more appropriate, and can take advantage of indexes (I don't have time to write an answer involving those right now!)

Comment: This will work - but it won't be very efficient since using `YEAR()` or `MONTH()` on your column basically prevents SQL Server from using any indices. If the OP needs this frequently, it might be useful to create two **computed, persisted** columns that hold the month/year for each row and then query on those.

Comment: @marc_s I completely agree, hence my (multiple!) warnings regarding your points, and only suggesting that this be used on very small datasets. I like your idea of the persisted computed columns though, why not go ahead and post your own answer (I'll even give you an upvote!)

Comment: Thanks all.  This runs once a month and at most there will be 250 records returned.

Answer (score 13):

Just as an alternative - this should use an index on DateFinished.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateFinished BETWEEN 
     DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
     AND 
     DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

Comment: This includes the first of the next month, I avoid this by making the last line: DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))

Comment: Good catch, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with @Bridge's method is use of index.
@Moose & @PCurd's method has a problems depending on how the data is stored.

@PCurd's method would work fine if all data collected on a day is rounded down to that day. E.g. event at 5pm is recorded as 2021-11-30 00:00:00. But if time is kept (which is assumed as it is a datetime field in Ops situation) then this data will be lost.

So you need to use the <> operators.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateFinished >= 
     DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
     AND DateFinished <
     DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
```

For the method using datefromparts: [SQL select records with current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111272/sql-select-records-with-current-month)