# How to get month to date data in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I manually change the date to my liking. How can I dynamically pull the current month to date data?

```
SELECT  SUM(op.price * op.qty)
FROM    dbo.Orders o
        INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersProduct op ON op.orderID = o.orderID
WHERE   o.ID IN ( xx, xx, xx, xx )   
AND o.orderDate BETWEEN '3/1/2016' AND '3/10/16'
```

Comment: [TSQL retrieve all records in current month/year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727800/tsql-retrieve-all-records-in-current-month-year)

Answer (score 0):

This will get month to date:

```
SELECT  SUM(op.price * op.qty)
FROM    dbo.Orders o
        INNER JOIN dbo.OrdersProduct op ON op.orderID = o.orderID
WHERE   o.ID IN ( xx, xx, xx, xx )   
        AND o.orderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
                        AND
                        DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```