# SQL select records with current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have a field name textbook date field name NewMonth 
The data like this

```
TextBook     NewMonth
ABC          2020-01-01
HDS          2020-01-30 
ZXY          2020-02-15
FGD          2020-02-01
YTS          2020-04-02
HFH          2020-04-05 
EDD          2020-03-25
```

My goal to select the records with current month (2020-04-XX)

```
TextBook     NewMonth
YTS          2020-04-02
HFH          2020-04-05
```

My query and not working. Can some one correct my query. Thank you

```
SELECT TextBook, NewMonth
   from  Store
   where NewMOnth >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -1, current_timestamp)), 0)
```

I think -1 for current month, -2 for last 2 months , -3 for last 3 months andso on

Comment: You really mean current month _and_ year, not just any date in, say, April of any year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My goal to select the records with current month (2020-04-XX)

Here is one option:

```
where NewMonth >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

If you need an upper bound too:

```
where 
    NewMonth >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
    and NewMonth < dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

If you want the previous month:

```
where 
    NewMonth >= dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
    and NewMonth < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1)
```

Or two months ago:

```
where 
    NewMonth >= dateadd(month, -2, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
    and NewMonth < dateadd(month, -1, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
```

Answer (score -2):

For 2020-04 you can use this :

```
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(NewMonth),MONTH(NewMonth)) = CONCAT('2020','04')
```

To select records with current month  :

```
WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(NewMonth),MONTH(NewMonth)) = CONCAT(now(),now())
```

Comment: I strongly recommend against using string concatenation to build dates. Use `datefromparts()` if you must, but not string manipulation. For example, in this particular case, the predicate is not SARGable; it can't use indexes.

Comment: in my case i trying to use FUNCTION  datefromparts() but MYSQL said that mydatabase.datefromparts() does not exist and the one way is concatenation and it worked

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server, not MySQL.